# insert new field and value in nested json list with using recursion in Python Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Please could any one tell me how to update/insert field and value in nested json list based on condition.

Like first my nested json list is like

```
objlist= [{ "label": "1", "children": [{ "label": "2", "children": [{ "label": "3" }]}]}{"label": "4","children": [{ "label": "5"},{ "label": "6"}]}{"label":"7"},{"label":"8"}]
```

after implement recursion and logic my output will like below\

```
objlist= [{ "label": "1", "children": [{ "label": "2", "children": [{ "label": "3" }]}], "checked":"true"}{"label": "4","children": [{ "label": "5", "checked":"true"},{ "label": "6"}]}{"label":"7"},{"label":"8", "checked":"true"}]
```

and achieve this the code would be written below

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    queryset = models.Master_Industry.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
    serializer1 = masterserializer.IndustrySerializer(queryset, many=True)
    json_string = json.dumps(serializer1.data)

    stringobj = 2,5
    my_dict = json.loads(json_string)

    for item in my_dict:
        if item["value"] in stringobj:
            item["checked"] = True
            continue

        for itemchild in item["children"]:
            if itemchild["value"] in stringobj:
                itemchild["checked"] = True
                continue

            for itemchildinner in itemchild["children"]:
                if itemchildinner["value"] in stringobj:
                    itemchildinner["checked"] = True
                    continue


    print(my_dict)
    return Response(serializer1.data)
```

So please tell me how to resolve this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your model structure or anything. But here is an idea on how to do this:

```
class LabelTree(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('label', 'children')
        model = Label

    def get_children(self, obj):
        children = Label.objects.filter(parent=obj)
        return LabelTree(children, many=True)
```

You find the children of your obj by filtering by the parent field and you serialize them. the code is not tested but The idea behind it should work.